# java: class, interface, or enum expected Error

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I'm tying to run the following java code for the insertion sorting algorithm and I get an error saying,

Error:  **java: class, interface, or enum expected**

```
public class InsertionSort {
    public static void insertionSort(int array[]) {
        int n = array.length;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            int key = array[j];
            int i = j - 1;
            while ((i > -1) && (array[i] > key)) {
                array[i + 1] = array[i];
                i--;
            }
            array[i + 1] = key;
        }
    }
}

    public static void main(String a[]){
        int[] arr1 = {9,14,3,2,43,11,58,22};
        System.out.println("Before Insertion Sort");
        for(int i:arr1){
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        insertionSort(arr1);//sorting array using insertion sort

        System.out.println("After Insertion Sort");
        for(int i:arr1){
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
    }
```

When I remove the Static keyword of the main function, the compiler does not display me the run option.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

1. You're getting the error message because you've tried to declare your `main()` method outside the scope of a class, which is not permitted.
2. The `main()` method is required to be `static` because otherwise it would need an instance of the class in order to invoke it, and therefore it would not work as an entry point into the program.